# Shielded sleeve?

Tags: cables, emc, shielding

Does anyone know of sleeving that is basically a hollow tube with a metal shield? Something like coax but without the core? I need to take some unshielded wires and run them through a flexible RF shielded tube. Wrapping them in copper tape is not good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copper braid tubing like the options in [this list](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv183=6223&FV=fff4001a%2Cfff802fb&k=copper%20braid&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) might suit.

Comment: This type of braid type material it is often quite loose fitting.  You might first cover the wire with a thin diameter heat shrink tubing then add the braid over that tubing, then cover all this with a larger diameter heat shrink tubing, finally shrink the whole thing, (making your own "coax" like wire system).  A longer end stripped wire could also be incorporated that touches the braid before shrinking which could provide a ground.